# Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem Proof Abbott (Ax. of Choice)

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice, proof-explanation

In Abbott's Proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, does Abbott use any form of the Axiom of Choice ?

I think he is since he chooses an $a_{n_k} \in I_k$ where there are multiple such $a_{n_k}$.

[image: Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem]

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277087/does-the-proof-of-bolzano-weierstrass-theorem-require-axiom-of-choice) and maybe also [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717961/countable-axiom-of-choice-why-you-cant-prove-it-from-just-zf).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I read those posts and understand that Bolzano-Weierstrass can be proved without AoC but I want to know whether Abbott is implicitly using it assuming he didn't intend any least $n$. Also what Abbott is using from the second post is DC axiom ?

Comment: That's really preposterous. A lot of people don't bother with the axiom of choice. Especially in basic analysis or topology. Why would he mind using the axiom? Not only that, it's formally debatable whether or not always strictly appealing to "pick this concrete witness" is the only way of avoiding choice, or if you are allowed, for example, to choose natural numbers arbitrarily because *there is* a canonical way to do so.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Im not saying that he would "mind" using the Axiom. Just that "Is he using it here?"  I am just trying to follow Abbott's reasoning in choosing any $a_{n_k} \in I_k$.

Comment: But I don't know what you mean by "using". If I tell you to construct some sequence of rationals which converge to $\pi$. And you pick each time a rational $\frac1n$-closer than the last choice. Have you used the axiom of choice? Or the fact that the rationals can be enumerated and then you can choose from them canonically mean that making somewhat arbitrary choices is fine?

Comment: @AsafKaragila From my understanding if you pick a rational closer than of the previous rational than you are not using choice(assuming that being $1/n$ closer makes the choice unique) since you specified that the $a_n$ is Exactly. But in Abbott's case he didnt specify the $a_{n_k}$ Exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure how you plan on using the fact that $\frac1n\to 0$ in order to choose a sequence of rationals approaching $\pi$. But that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be clearly understood that most non-logicians don't care so much whether they use AC or not, so it is difficult to say whether they are unaware that they are using AC or whether they know how to avoid AC but just never say it.

Here, for example, one could 'argue' that "select a half" uses DC (dependent choice), because the English indefinite determiner "a" does not stipulate any specific choice, and each selection depends on the previous selections. However, as we ought to know, the use of DC here is trivially eliminated by saying "select the leftmost half" instead.

Similarly, the choice of each $n_k$ in the proof **exactly as written** can be argued to use DC, again because of the use of indefinite determiners "some" and "an", and since each choice depends on the previous one. In other words, there is no clue that the author is aware of the use of DC, but also no evidence that the author is not. As before, this use of DC is easily eliminated by saying "select $n_k$ to be the least natural number greater than $n_{k-1}$ such that $a_{n_k} ∈ I_k$". Once we do that, the sequence $(n_k)_{k∈\mathbb{N}}$ can be constructed by a trivial application of the recursion theorem, which does **not** need any choice whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Choice is not used to "select a half for which this is the case", because we can just pick the lower half if we need to make a choice.

Choice is not used to select an $a_{n_1}$ because we can pick the least $n$ such that $a_n \in I_1$. However, to select all of the $n_i$ together, we use the axiom of dependent choice (which is a very weak choice principle, but it implies countable choice).

Comment: We CAN pick the least $n$ but Abbott never mentions that he does so ? Thus I am assuming he is using Ax. of Choice.

Comment: @Nameless Sure, but for that matter he doesn't say he's working in $\mathbb{R}$. We assume some modicum of common sense when reading the proof. Just because he doesn't mention it doesn't mean he didn't mean it; in this text, he's not interested in whether choice is used or not, so he doesn't mention it.

Comment: I am just checking to see whether my reasoning whether he is using Choice or not implicit is correct since I am relatively new to proof. But I get from you that "technically" he is implicitly using it but its usage could be avoided by choosing the least $n$. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. (He's still using a choice principle which cannot be proved from ZF: dependent choice. DC is not as strong as the full AC, though.)

Comment: I don't think we actually need dependent choice here. Since at every step we have a choice procedure, at no point we need to make "arbitrary choice".

Comment: @Wojowu But every "non-arbitrary" choice depends on the previous ones, because we need the $n_i$ to form an increasing sequence.

Comment: @Wojowu Although I am now unsure in the light of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277087/does-the-proof-of-bolzano-weierstrass-theorem-require-axiom-of-choice

Comment: @PatrickStevens I am almost certain we don't need DC here. We can define, explicitly, the sequence recursively using "$n_1=1,n_2=f(n_1),n_3=f(n_1,n_2),\dots$", where I am using $f$ to denote the procedure. Since recursive constructions provably define sequences, this is an object which provably exists in ZF.

Comment: @Wojowu So is he using AoC ?

Comment: @Nameless No, I am pretty sure this proof goes through without any use of axiom of choice.

Comment: @Wojowu just to clarify. I KNOW you can prove this theorem without AoC. My question is : Is Abbott implicitly using AoC since he chooses arbitrary $a_{n_k} \in I_k$ ? He is using choice on th $n_i$'s.

Comment: @Nameless If he says "arbitrary", then he is using choice. _However_, there is an easy "fix" - simply choose the smallest $n_k$ possible. Then, per discussion above, we need no choice.

Comment: @Wojowu's guess is correct. No choice is needed to construct a sequence such that each term is the least natural greater than the previous one that satisfies some property. So your second paragraph claiming you need DC is wrong.