# Is there a hidden use of choice in the proof of the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

*Every bounded infinite sequence of real numbers contains a convergent subsequence*

Proof:

Let $E$ the infinite set of values of the sequence.

$E$ bounded and infinite $\Rightarrow E$ contains a limit point $x$.

$x$ limit point of $E \Rightarrow \exists n_1 \in \mathbb{N}:|x_{n_1}-x|<1$.

So by induction if $\exists n_k \in \mathbb{N}:|x_{n_k}-x|<\frac{1}{k}$ then $\exists n_{k+1} \in \mathbb{N}:|x_{n_{k+1}}-x|<\frac{1}{k+1}$, otherwise $x$ is not a limit point of $X$.

So, the sequence constructed $\{x_{n_1},x_{n_2},...,x_{n_k},...\}$ converges to $x$.

End Proof.

In the last step *So, the sequence constructed...* is there the axiom of choice in a hidden form?
Otherwise how can I justify the construction of the set $\{x_{n_1},x_{n_2},...,x_{n_k},...\}$?

Comment: related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707659/bolzano-weierstrass-theorem-proof-abbott-ax-of-choice

Comment: @Fallen Nope, no choice.

Comment: Perhaps a more descriptive title is in order?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree, put "Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem" somewhere is the title

Answer (score 6):

There is no essential use of choice here. The natural numbers, as you probably know, are well-ordered.

That means that whenever you have to make a choice, you can always choose the one with the least index.

This is a situation that happens often in analysis, mainly because for the most part doing analysis without [at least dependent] choice is borderline self-abusive.

(Do note, by the way that "$E$ contains a limit point" is wrong, and you should say that "$E$ *has* a limit point" instead.)

Comment: But don't you need some version of AC to prove that such limit $x$ exists?

Comment: No, you're talking about a countable set, so it's not hard to show it has a monotone subsequence going somewhere.

Comment: @FallenApart In detail: suppose I have an infinite set $B$ contained in $[0, 1]$ (for simplicity). We define a sequence of closed intervals $I_n$ as follows: $I_0=[0, 1]$. $I_{n+1}$ is the left half of $I_n$ if there are infinitely many elements of $B$ in the left half of $I_n$, and is the right half of $I_n$ otherwise. Since $B$ is infinite, by induction we always have $I_n\cap B$ infinite. The intersection $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n$ has exactly one element, and this element is clearly a limit point of $B$. No choice is used anywhere.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for this detailed explenations. So we only use [the recursion thm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem) to define sequence of sets $I_n$?