# Do we need the Axiome of Choice in proving a Sequentially Compact Metric Space is Totally Bounded?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, axiom-of-choice, recursion

I'm really wondering if the Axiom of Choice is essential in this proof.

Comment: Also, or perhaps more suitably, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277087/does-the-proof-of-bolzano-weierstrass-theorem-require-axiom-of-choice

Comment: In the thread you just linked, they were facing the problem of choosing an element for each of the intervals. I'm referring instead to the creation of this sequence of intervals.

Comment: @AsafKaraglia : ​ Both questions you point to seem to be about bounded subsets of the real numbers, rather than general sequentially-compact metric spaces. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Asaf was pointing to a precise post where a counterexample was given. It was very helpful and I got the fact Axiom of Dependent Choice is necessary for this proof.

Comment: However, note that Countable Choice is enough for this _result_ (via a different proof). ​ ​